# Default CRC input to reproduce check value

Tags: crc

I found a site where a lot of CRC values are listed, with configurations/setup. There is also a "check" value, which I believe is generated with some kind of default input (some dummy string or such).

Does anybody know what this is and/or how I can reproduce it?

Sample config: `width=3 poly=0x3 init=0x7 refin=true refout=true xorout=0x0 check=0x6 name="CRC-3/ROHC"`

Site: http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/all.htm#crc.cat.arc
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, found the solution.

HEX: `0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34 0x35 0x36 0x37 0x38 0x39`

String: `123456789`